# Inverse Explosion with Unity2d

Tags: 2d, unity, javascript, physics, rigid-body-dynamics

I am currently trying to make all other objects push away from the player when the player explodes. It currently works, but it pushes close objects a little and far objects very far. What I want is for close objects to get pushed back more than far objects.
Here is the current code:

```
function explode () {
var all_rigidbodies = FindObjectsOfType(Rigidbody2D);

for (var r : Rigidbody2D in all_rigidbodies) {
    if (Vector2.Distance(r.transform.position, transform.position) < 6 && r.tag != "Player") {
        var px : float = r.transform.position.x - transform.position.x;
        var py : float = r.transform.position.y - transform.position.y;

        r.AddForce((Vector2(px, py) * 200), ForceMode2D.Force);             
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to inverse the vector or force, or better ways to achieve 2D explosions?

**EDIT:** Ended up just normalizing force so its all the same knockback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you change the last line to this it should work.

```
r.AddForce(Vector2(px, py).normalized * EXPLOSION_FORCE / Vector2.Distance(r.transform.position, transform.position));
```

normalize sets the vector to be length 1, then you multiply by some force and divide by the distance, so the further away it is, the less force is given.